# How to run install.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

When running

```
/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php
```

I receive the following error:

```
'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/podemost/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2672'
```

Comment: Did you modified something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you edit the functions file in WordPress?

You could download WordPress and then upload a fresh functions.php file to your server to replace the broken file.

Never edit any files in the WordPress folder.

Make all changes in the form of a child theme.